# If statement is not working with my getText().toString()

Tags: java, if-statement, android-edittext, tostring

Before I start explaining I'll just get you into the code.

```
EditText br = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

if ( br.getText().toString() == "0") {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

It's that simple. But I don't understand why it doesn't work! I typed in `("1" == "1")` in the `if` statements just to see if there is anything else wrong. But the message shows up on my phone.

The `edittext` field has the number 0 on it. I have no clue why this simple if statement would not work.

Comment: Check out that duplicate. Don't use `==` to compare the contents of strings.

Comment: yep, use equals to compare strings in java e.g. "0".equals( br.getText().toString())